# Disable formula field

Tags: trigger, workflow, formula

How to disable formula field (formula failed calculated Now() - CreadatedDate ) when case owner will be change

Answer (score 2):

Formulas are always calculated when the record is queried. If you want a persistent value, you'd want to make a number field, and create a workflow rule or process builder that sets the field when the number field is blank and the owner changes (or whatever criteria you want to use).

Comment: Actually i am using formula field as Text data type so it can be disable

Comment: @parwajkhan, do not get confused with field type and datatype. +1 to sfdcfox